# how to know if there is a consecutivly increasing five values in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an vector and I need to know if there is any five consecutive numbers where the values increases (sorted). I found a solution but I am sure that there is another solution which will be more efficient. Any help?

My Code:

```
A = [10 4 1  2 3 4 1 2];
for i  =1 :length(A)-5
    temp = A(i:i+5);
    sor(i) = issorted(temp);
end
```

Comment: +1 for arriving at a solution and posting working code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to compute changes and [`conv`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) to accumulate over a window of `n=5` consecutive values:

```
n = 5;
result = any(conv(double(diff(A)>0), ones(1,n), 'valid')==n);
```

The variable `result` will be `1` (`true`) if the condition is met, and `0` (`false`) otherwise.

You may want to replace `>` by `>=`.

If you need to know the *starting indices* of each run of `n` consecutive positive changes, use `find` instead of `any`:

```
starts = find(conv(double(diff(A)>0), ones(1,n), 'valid')==n);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfect .. I will accept it as an answer within 7 mins .. also I have a small question .. how can I remove any consecutive duplicates in A ?

Comment: To remove consecutive duplicates you can again use `diff`: `A(1+find(diff(A)==0)) = []`

Comment: I mean If I need to make a new array "B" which is the same like "A" but without the consecutive duplicates?

Comment: `B = A; B(1+find(diff(B)==0)) = []` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, and what if I need to know if there is decreasing values (same problem but five consecutivly decreasing numbers)??

Comment: Just replace `>` by `<`